# Is there open source TCP server for android clients?

Tags: android, tcp, messaging, tcpclient, apache-mina

I searching for an open source TCP server that can be configured on the computer to work as server for client applications for Android. As I want to create messaging services between Android devices,

I've found Apache Mina open source TCP server, does it work for android OS ?

### edit

sorry, for `Mina`, I don't mean the server, I mean the general framework. Can I create android java client for android using `Apache Mina`

Comment: I assume you can open TCP sockets in android. Then there's no "does it work for android OS". It's a TCP server, it works for everything.

Comment: You can create TCP Sockets, but TCP is a transport layer protocol only. The "Server" means, it should have an Application layer protocol, just like HTTP, SMTP etc.

Comment: @Vishnu I will create the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a tcp server I use a simple java application which consists of 1 class. Here it is. Hope this will help you!

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class PortMonitor {
    private static int port = 8080;


    /**
     * JavaProgrammingForums.com
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //Port to monitor
        final int myPort = port;
        ServerSocket ssock = new ServerSocket(myPort);
        System.out.println("port " + myPort + " opened");

        Socket sock = ssock.accept();
        System.out.println("Someone has made socket connection");

        OneConnection client = new OneConnection(sock);
        String s = client.getRequest();

    }

}

class OneConnection {
    Socket sock;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    DataOutputStream out = null;

    OneConnection(Socket sock) throws Exception {
        this.sock = sock;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
        out = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
    }

    String getRequest() throws Exception {
        String s = null;
        while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("got: " + s);
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use a simple example, I want to work on a more complex project, where the efficiency and scalability are the most things I matter about